# Применить this для вывода картинок по нажатию на кнопки

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Boston</button>
    <button>Acapulco</button>
</div>
<div class="tables">
    <img src="images/boston.jpg" id="image1">
    <img src="images/acapulco.jpg" id="image2">
</div>
```

Надо, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку выдавало 1 соответствующую кнопке картинку.Как это сделать с this, чтобы не писать отдельный код на каждую картинку, если их 100?

Максимум, что у меня получилось (но всё равно неверно):

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $((this).'img').css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: Вынесите в отдельный атрибут навазние картинки в теге img. Потом у кнопки получите текст и по нему найдете нужный img. Любые способы не связанные с четкой идентификацие объекта, на который нужно влиять, кажутся костылями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так подозреваю хотели что-то типа такого:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var idx = $(this).index();
  $('.tables img:eq(' + idx + ')').show();  // $('.tables img[id=image' + (++idx) + ']').show();
});
```

```css
.tables img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Boston</button>
    <button>Acapulco</button>
</div>
<div class="tables">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rIH-NcvXJTk/TVRv2_xk9rI/AAAAAAAAANE/AVGEB-arWXk/s1600/images.jpg" id="image1">
    <img src="https://i.mycdn.me/image?id=605295869202&t=0&plc=WEB&tkn=*X-f02Q2b_3NyhFEHYNv-jfbAsmg" id="image2">
</div>
```

То есть каждый индекс кнопки соответствует индексу картинки. Правда если индексы не будут в точности параллельно соответствовать, то стоит применить другую стратегию.

В данном случае используется **[index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)**, для получения номера элемента в коллекции и **[eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** для извлечения по данному индексу из другой.

Comment: А можете прояснить, пожалуйста, 2 вещи: 1. Как отображается картинка, если в css display:none? 2.часть выражения ('+ idx+') - что это?  Нигде не могу найти внятное объяснение использован + в jQuery или JS в такого рода выражениях (не в циклах либо математических выражениях - там смысл знака + понятен).

Comment: А можете прояснить, пожалуйста, 2 вещи:

Comment: `Как отображается картинка, если в css display:none?` - метод `.show()` как раз делает дисплей блок..... метод `hide()` - дисплей none соответственно............`.часть выражения ('+ idx+') - что это?` - это конкатенация.... так как переменная в кавычках интерпретируется как строка, то её надо выносить из строки......а как её вынести и оставить как часть строки? конкатенацией, что и делают плюсы

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на любую из кнопок, в html выводилась только одна картинка, а не все картинки поочередно? Т.е. одна кнопка - одна картинка, без выведения всех картинок после всех нажатий всех кнопок.

Comment: @Alex скрывать все картинки, а потом показывать только ту, что с индексом

Comment: Снова неверно, но у меня получилось только так: 

$('button').on('click', function(){
  var idx = $(this).index();
    if($('.tables img:eq(' + idx + ')').show())  {
        ($('.tables img.hide()'));
    }
});
Если настоящий индексный номер картинки появляется, то другие картинки прячутся. Должно работать, но никак...

Comment: @Alex не мудри.......`$('.tables img').hide(); var idx = $(this).index();
  $('.tables img:eq(' + idx + ')').show();`